# Changing the default page from Pages module

Tags: templates, module, pages

I am still learning Expression Engine so please forgive any misunderstanding or ignorance that I might have. I am using the Pages module and I want to be able to set which page is the default page for the whole site regardless of which template is used. Is this possible? If I need to elaborate upon any details please inform me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that from the Pages module. You can set the default template, and then, in that template, call a specific entry by entry_id.

This is an example of what I typically do in the default template (site home page)--e.g., site/index:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    entry_id="1"
    channel="home_page"
    disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination|categories"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
}

... your template and page content...

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So, the template is pulling in a single entry's content. And, it's not using the Page URI at all on the entry with entry_id = 1.

Would that work for you? It's not exactly what you described, but you *can't* literally set a default Page for the site.

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot, thanks! But how do you know what entry_id a particular page has... I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Ok one way is to search for it in edit.

Comment: Right, you generally grab the entry_id from the Edit screen in the control panel. This is the one case where I reference an Entry ID on an EE site.

Comment: If you didn't want to use an Entry ID, you alternatively could use a unique URL Title for the default entry. But, each Entry ID is always unique for the entire site (and, actually across multiple sites if you use the Multiple Site Manager add-on). An entry URL Title is only guaranteed to be unique per channel--you'd have to humanly enforce uniqueness for the URL across the site.